# Problema com autenticação Django

Tags: python, django, autenticação, firebird, login

Estou com problema na hora de validar o login, estou usando um banco legado firebird 2.5.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O banco de dados está sincronizado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a mensagem de erro que aparece no screen shot o problema é que a tabela `USUARIO` não possui a coluna `USERNAME`. Você já verificou se as colunas necessárias para a autenticação do Django funcionar já foram criadas na tabela `USUARIO`?

Pelos parâmetros que você está passando para o `authenticate()` parece você criou um backend de autenticação novo, se esse foi realmente o caso verifique se o método `authenticate()` do seu backend está pegando o usuário corretamente.